Azure Functions and ADB2C integration
I have an Azure Functions application (API), which consists of HTTP-triggered functions.
Also, I have Azure Active Directory B2C tenant and signup/signin policy, which I use for user identities.
I planned following flow for working with API:

User registers/authenticates in a web application using ADB2C + MSAL
User makes requests to my API, passing access_token value from the authentication to Authorization header
Azure automatically processes token, extracts user data, and makes it available in request.user field inside my function.

My API function code:
const { app } = require("@azure/functions");

app.http("HelloWorld", {
  methods: ["GET", "POST"],
  authLevel: "anonymous",
  handler: async (request, context) => {
    context.log(`Http function processed request for url "${request.url}"`);

    // Debug
    context.log(request.user);

    const name = request.query.get("name") || (await request.text()) || "world";
    const user = request.user ? JSON.stringify(user) : null;

    return { body: `Hello, ${name}! User data: ${user}` };
  },
});

I tried to enable auth from Azure Functions -> My App -> Preferences -> Authentication settings.
It created a new App Registration in ADB2C.
However this app registration has following notification:
"You can use this application to authenticate against Microsoft Entra ID, but not Azure AD B2C."

Also, token acquired from this app registration did not authorize my requests to function.
But there was interesting moment:
I could reach functions app url, which got me through auth flow (which looked like standard MS auth, not my policy), then redirected to page saying Your Functions 4.0 app is up and running.
I've tried to perform HTTP request from this page using developer console, and it worked.
I've checked the request info in Network tab and discovered that my request was authorized by Cookie AppServiceAuthSession.

I also tried different approach.
I've created App Registration manually, attached it to function app, set jwt.ms as a redirect path, acquired token this way, but when trying to authenticate my request with this token, it didn't work.
I also tried accessing Function App url, it went me through auth process, but after entering creds it redirected my to https://<my-app-url>/.auth/login/aad/callback with message:
You do not have permission to view this directory or page.

Third approach was a hacky: I tried to use automatically created app registration, but with issuer URL from App Registration I've created manually. I got following error after trying to authenticate:
The provided application with ID 'APP_ID' is not valid against this service. Please use an application created via the B2C portal and try again.
It makes me think that this functionality is incompatible with ADB2C and I need to write a middleware to do the job. But a confirmation from experienced Azure users or team members would be highly appreciated.

While trying to make it work I used following articles as a reference:
Elio Struyf: Securing your Azure Functions with an existing Azure AD app
Arjen van Benten: How to secure Azure Functions with Azure B2C
And Azure Docs.
I tried both headers: Authorization: Bearer %access_token% and Authorization: %access_token%.
--
Questions:

Is my logic correct about how it should work?

Is it possible to authenticate requests with Authorization token, or it can be made by using cookies only?

Should I use Microsoft Entra ID or Microsoft Entra External ID instead of ADB2C?



To secure Azure Function using Azure AD B2C check the below:
Create an  Azure AD B2C application  and expose an API:

Grant  API permissions  for the exposed scope:

I created an HTTP trigger:


Make sure to add redirect URL as https://YourfunctionAppName.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad/callback

Added  Identity provider as Microsoft and passed the values of Azure AD B2C application:

The issuer must be in the format https://b2c.b2clogin.com/b2c.onmicrosoft.com/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration?p=B2C_1_susi
Using Postman I generated access token and able to call the HTTP trigger successfully:
GET https://rukkfa.azurewebsites.net/api/HttpTrigger1

Grant type: Authorization code 

Callback URL: https://FunctionAppName.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad/callback
Auth URL:  https://b2c.b2clogin.com/b2c.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_testruk/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
Token URL : https://b2c.b2clogin.com/b2c.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_testruk/oauth2/v2.0/token
Client ID : ClientID
Client Secret : ClientSecret
Scope: https://b2c.onmicrosoft.com/ClientID/API.Call


Decoded access token:


Thank you for response! Could please tell me how did you authorize your API call: via cookies or Authorization header? And do you have user data available in request.user inside your func?

I used Authorization header to pass the access token

By some reason, not working for me :c Probably I missed something, but I'm struggling in even acquiring JWT using Postman.

Can you paste the screenshot of how are generating token in postman? And what is the error you are getting

I'm getting "You do not have permission to view this directory or page." error.
I can successfully acquire access token via Postman.

here are my setup in screenshots:
https://i.imgur.com/ZzvfEi8.png - adb2c app registration
https://i.imgur.com/azoKutL.png - adb2c api permission
https://i.imgur.com/eXcvMuZ.png - function app auth settings

Did you follow the same steps as me?

Did you create function/http trigger as anonymous

I believe it's all the same steps. Function is anonymous. But I even can't reach page "Your function app is up and running". It tries to authenticate me, then redirects to /.auth/login/aad/callback page and that's it.

did you enable this? https://i.imgur.com/pA3dm74.png

@capchuck can you decode the token and paste the screenshot?

The error is due to the allowed audience you have configured in the function app, it must be the ClientID of the application not the https://xxxxx

Decoded token: https://i.imgur.com/I4gXc0g.png

Yeah change the allowed audience as ClientID in function app. And then call the http trigger it will be successful

like this? https://i.imgur.com/Nlku7WQ.png

Yes remove the API.Call

But my api is exposed in https://xxxxx format : https://i.imgur.com/VD2bd62.png

Thats okay even I have exposed in the same format.

When you generate access token the aud claim will the ClientID and hence it should match the allowed token audiences in the function app that is it must be the ClientID only

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
